# Ant build failed with error "SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute"

Tags: java, ant

```
D:\Test>ant -v
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: D:\Test\build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.5 in: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\jre
Detected OS: Windows XP
parsing buildfile D:\Test\build.xml with URI = file:/D:/Test/build.xml
Project base dir set to: D:\Test

BUILD FAILED
D:\Test\build.xml:6: Open quote is expected for attribute "dir" associated with an  elemen
t type  "mkdir".
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:320)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:178)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:82)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:793)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Open quote is expected for attribute "dir" assoc
iated with an  element type  "mkdir".
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseExcep
tion(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:236)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHan
dlerWrapper.java:215)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorRe
porter.java:386)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorRe
porter.java:316)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.
java:1441)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(XMLScanne
r.java:802)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(
XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:578)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartEleme
nt(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:222)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$Fragment
ContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1693)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocu
ment(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:368)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Config
uration.java:834)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Config
uration.java:764)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:148)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXP
arser.java:1242)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:307)
        ... 6 more

Total time: 0 seconds

D:\Test>
```

When I run the ant-v command instead of creating the build I got the above message and everything regarding variables was done correctly. I was unable to correct it and create the build. Can any one rectify the mistake?

build.xml:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<project name="test" default="compile" basedir=".">
    <property name="src" value="."/>
    <property name="build" value="build"/>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you copy the build.xml file on here? maybe @sudocode it's right, but we need more info to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looks like you have invalid content in your build.xml file (missing open quote) at line 6.

You might have something like this

```
<mkdir dir=foo/>
```

You need something like this

```
<mkdir dir="foo"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean that my answer helped you or not. If not, please post the content (or at least the start) of your build.xml file.

Comment: Thanks friend, the answer u have given is right as per the syntax but in my PC it is giving an error as above and even though I have corrected and tried, the same is repeating.

Comment: Strange. I can execute the build file you posted without error. But if I remove the opening quote from the mkdir dir attribute, I reproduce your error. Are you sure you are editing the same buildfile that you are executing? (BTW, you should post the buildfile in your question, where it can be formatted, not in a comment).